# J2ME chat application?

Tags: java, java-me

I want to develop a chat application using J2ME.Any reference code example or code
or any kind help can help me......
in my application.In my application message will go from one mobile to the server(Tomcat) first there i will save it in my database and then look msisdn and forword this message to the that msisdn

Comment: Have you chosen a protocol? Will everything pass through a server, or is the server only used to find peers? More info needed.

Comment: @Emyr yes i want to choose TCP protocol in my application.In my application message will go from one mobile to the server(Tomcat) first there i will save it in my database and then look msisdn and forword this message to the that msisdn.

Comment: @Emyr any type of help regarding to this is very helpful for me

Comment: Use XMPP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP and read Nubsis's Answer.

Comment: @Emyr any code example regarding to this protocal in j2me

Comment: XMPP libs for Java, pick one: http://xmpp.org/software/libraries.shtml#java

Answer (score 1):

After a quick google search I found this:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/Socketconnection.htm

Read the documentation on StreamConnection and Connection. That should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use HTTP and have a servlet write to a file which the clients download?