# how to write a chat program just like gtalk or yahoo

Tags: java, java-me, client-server, chat

i am developing a project in which the client and server should communicate asynchronously after ensuring the security.i made all the coding that is required to authenticate a client now it's the turn for communication. My mind is blank can anyone suggest me how to develop it... another thing is server is in j2se and client in j2me..
plz guys my project is based upon your responses help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [discussion](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?80667-please-tell-me-the-process-to-build-chat-server-using-J2ME) on nokia forum and [existing discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370126/j2me-chat-application) on same in this forum. Here also discussed on same topic. It may be useful for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Find an implementation of [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) and have most of your work done for you...

Comment: aahh... i've seen xmpp website but i am not able to find it. can u tell me in detail

Comment: Stackoverflow can't do your project for you, just answer a few questions. The web-site has an explanation of the  links to a number of different books on the subject, and clients, servers and library software that will be useful.